# sum of all columns in a two dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays

How can I add column values in a two dimenstional array? For example

```
[[11.9, 12.2, 12.9],
 [15.3, 15.1, 15.1], 
 [16.3, 16.5, 16.5],
 [17.7, 17.5, 18.1]]
```

I want it to result to:

```
[61.2,61.3,62.6]
```

I have tried this so far:

```
Btotals.append(sum(float(x)) for x in zip(totals))
```

However it gave me this:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02A42878>]
```

Comment: [sum(x) for x in zip(*totals)]

Comment: @CSZ thanks for the help..

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `numpy` for this? With `numpy` it would be: `numpy.sum(a, axis=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the argument to zip first.

```
a = [[11.9, 12.2, 12.9],
    [15.3, 15.1, 15.1], 
    [16.3, 16.5, 16.5],
    [17.7, 17.5, 18.1]]
result = [sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
>>> [61.2, 61.3, 62.6]
```

Comment: If you want to do anything more complicated, I agree with @Akavall, `numpy` would be the way to go.

Comment: how can I get the sum of square of each element in `a`?

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is a variable containing your 2d array, try

```
[sum([row[i] for row in array]) for i in range(len(array[0]))]
```